# Can't get my CSS to Float right

Tags: html, css, web

I'm following the Udemy complete web development course. I'm supposed to be making a clone of the BBC website but I'm having a couple of issues. First of all my font is much bigger than this, set to the same 0.75em. Also my h1 tag seems to be to the right of the

tag so I am guessing I've messed up with the flow somewhere but can't see how.

http://jsbin.com/yowoyohaja/1/edit?html,output

Comment: right click and select 'Inspect Element' to check what is happening to your css. to me it seems like your font was set to 0.75em on the content div, but that font is overwritten by the div's child elements.

Comment: Oh you're right. I seem to have messed up the div tags. #newsbar should not be a parent to #content. They should both be under the #container...

Comment: Right , that was the problem. Thanks. Inspect element is handy.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, you would like the header to be above the date?

If that's the case then simply move the H1 tag to above the date in the HTML and ensure all your open tags are closed, as your H1 tag was left open. See updated jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/cetokibuva/1/edit

Comment: Any idea why my h1 tag is not blue? I have updated the jsbin. http://jsbin.com/vuyiwofope/1/edit?html,output

Comment: @neil use 'color' not 'font-color'

Comment: like this:  #content h1 { color: #1F4F82;}